# PHP замена атрибутов в HTML теге

Tags: php, html, dom

Прошу советов от специалистов в PHP, по такой задаче:

Хочу в *хедер.php* разместить скрипт который будет проходить по всему нижележащему DOM и заменять путь в srс, на тот который находится в data-src. Или как вариант, data-src затирает src и соответственно вырезается "data-" из названия атрибута понимаю, как сделать это на JS:

```
document.onreadystatechange = function() {
    var imgArray = document.querySelectorAll("img[data-src]");
    for (i = 0; i < imgArray.length; i++ ){
        imgArray[i].src = imgArray[i].dataset.src;
    }
};
```

а с PHP мало знаком, поэтому не знаю насколько целесообразно пытаться разобраться, например, с этим: *http://docs.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php*
или существуют какие-то другие способы, если вообще существуют...

P.S. причина всей этой заварушки: с помощью *mobile_detect.php* я определяю мобильные устройства + плохие браузеры, и там эту замену производить не буду, плюс там подключается lazyload или просто отложенная загрузка изображений

Comment: Вы совсем не понимаете как использовать PHP для своей задачи. Так что лучше используйте PHP по минимуму.

Comment: @YuriyProkopets Спасибо, за совет :) Да, я стараюсь не касаться его. Показалось, что есть простое костыльное решение, которое я не вижу из-за нехватки опыта. 
я так понимаю что решить можно только одним из способов как здесь описано: https://toster.ru/q/6344 ?

Comment: Основная идея которую вы должны понимать, это то что PHP генерирует текст (HTML). И этот текст (HTML) можно генерировать на основании разных логик. Для вашей задачи нужно просто определить тип браузера и "передать" это в HTML и уже на стороне клиента (в браузере) использовать эти данные

Comment: @YuriyProkopets понятно. основная проблема возникла в том, что картинки из src грузятся быстрее, нежели их туда вставлять при domcontentloaded. но менять php шаблоны я не хотел, поэтому думал о глобальном решение: какую разметку отдавать браузеру из PHP

Comment: "какую разметку отдавать браузеру из PHP" -за это как раз и должен отвечать шаблон. Если "плохой" браузер, то пишем в `data-src` и javascript-ом заменяем. А если "нормальный" браузер, то сразу пишем в  `src`